# Is there an easy way to see your starred questions?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

There are [some questions](https://superuser.com/q/354513/81403) I tend to need to reference quite often.

Is there a way for me to see my starred questions, without clicking on [my username](https://meta.superuser.com/users/81403/wizlog) and viewing my list of starred questions? 
*(this includes adding a favorite to my browser)*

Could there be a starred tab under the "Stack **Exchange**" in the upper left corner (not sure what to call it).

Comment: I don't see the advantage it turning two clicks into three and cluttering the menu further just to save a page load.

Comment: The ["favorites"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xT1cm.png) text in the pop-up from your username at the top is actually a link, and will take you straight to the favourites tab of your account. That's pretty much the fastest you can get there at the moment. Or is the point that you don't want to use the site-provided favourites at all?

Comment: @MatthewRead Yes, I wanted to avoid the page load.

Comment: @DMA57361 Thank you,  I hadn't noticed the The "favorites" text in the pop-up from my username.

Post this as an answer, and I'll probably accept it.

Comment: Notifying @DMA57361 again: Come on, we need you to make this topic greener!

Comment: That's @DanielBeck, for some reason wizlog's ping above never reached my inbox... :/

Answer (score 4):

The `favorites` link on the pop-up from your user name —

[image]

— will take you straight to the favourites tab of your account.

That's pretty much the fastest you can get there at the moment.